# How to getback from external link in webview in iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am using PhoneGap to show website in I phone application. I have used window.open and it's working fine but when we click on any external link then we do not have any option to come back in iPhone.

So is there any back? I can know that we are viewing external website so that we can open that phone browser or any other solution.

Comment: use the _blank option, so the page is opened on an internal browser instead of opening it on safari. There is no way of comming back from safari

Comment: Safari View Controller might let you stay in the app, check it out.

Comment: i have use one website i want then when i click on that link then it open in same browser but i opened any external website then it should open in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a toolbar with the cordova InAppBrowser plugin that has back, forward and close buttons. To further customize the app browser, please refer to the [InAppBrowser plugin documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). This code will open your website in a modal webview.

```
window.open("https://www.google.com", _blank', 'toolbar=yes')
```

This behavior can be changed by replacing _blank with one of the following attributes:

> - _self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
> - _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
> - _system: Opens in the system's web browser.